# ADO.NET Entities Framework Performance Tips Every Developer Should Know

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

What are the performance tips that every ADO.NET EF developer should know about?

Please put each tip per answer and explain why the tip is good (e.g. by minimizing DB roundtrips).

Answer (score 9):

Use `ObjectContext#GetObjectByKey()` to retrieve entities by their key instead of using `First()` (or `FirstOrDefault`) operator in the LINQ query.  The latter will hit the database everytime while the former will search the EF cache (`ObjectStateManager` to be specific) for the entity first and won't hit the database if the entity with the specified key is found.

References

- [MSDN documentation on ObjectContext#GetObjectByKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjectbykey.aspx)
- [GetObjectbyKey in E.F. vs. Querying for a single entity](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2008/08/06/GetObjectbyKeyInEFVsQueryingForASingleEntity.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

A thing I've just learned when profiling the SQLs generated by EF code used in my application: there is a difference between:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = DB.User.Where(...);
int count = users.Count();
```

and

```
IQueryable<User> users = DB.User.Where(...);
int count = users.Count();
```

The former generates a full query to retrieve matched rows from the `User` table and the counting is done after the data has been transferred back to EF.  The latter does what is generally expected: generate a `SELECT COUNT ...` SQL, which is much more efficient.

This is quite subtle but not difficult to figure why after noticing about it: it is due to the statically bound nature of C# extension method.

A small technique to get around this is to use the "var" keyword to declare the variable:

```
var users = DB.users.Where(...);
int count = users.Count();
```

This will cause "users" to be declared as the same type that ".Where" returns; which is an IQueryable<>.

Comment: This is a good example of why we should use recommend 'var' over specific variable type.

Answer (score 4):

Assume we have `BlogPost` entity references `User` entity via the `Author` property.  Instead of specifying a full `User` entity to the `BlogPost.Author` property (which might require a database roundtrip), initializing the reference with the correct `EntityKey`.  For example:

```
BlogPost.AuthorReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("EFNamespace.User", "Id", userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way to update detached entity objects. It's an extension method.

```
public static void AttachUpdated(this ObjectContext obj, EntityObject objectDetached)
{
    if (objectDetached.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        object original;
        if (obj.TryGetObjectByKey(objectDetached.EntityKey, out original))
            obj.ApplyPropertyChanges(objectDetached.EntityKey.EntitySetName, objectDetached);
        else
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    }
}
```